# Approval Process - Submitter Can Approve

Tags: approval-process, summer-16

I have an `Approval Process` on a custom `Quote__c` object. For some reason now it appears that any submitter can approve his/her own quote. We have not made any changes, only difference I can see is that we are on Summer 16 now. None of the affected users are listed as approvers and none have modify all data permissions.

Comment: If this is truly the case, meaning your setup history shows no changes, you should file a case on this with Salesforce Support.

Comment: Did you look the option in approval process.All Administrators and approver's  can modify record.@SLM3573